# ExtJS 4.2 locked editable grid issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

If you take a look at this [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30jf), its from Sencha examples `Locking Grouping Grid with Summary`. But I have edited a bit the example.

If you clic on the first row, second column (`Integrate 2.0 Forms with 2.0 Layouts`), it starts edit the cell, don´t change nothing and press enter, I want the view to start edit the same cell of the next row, but it only "focus" that cell, it doesn´t start editing the cell.

Am I missing something in the code?Any idea if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add the following line at the bottom of your method :

```
eOpts.stopPropagation();
```

Your code was working well but the "press ENTER" event you intercepts close the new cell you just started to edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect in the sencha fiddle, I will try now on my real project and see if it works like in the fiddle